# Jquery pass a jquery method with arguments as function's parameter

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if and how you can pass a jquery command as function's parameter

```
var childs = ["#foo", "#bar"];

loopTheChilds("trigger('change')");

loopTheChilds("prop( 'disabled', true )");

var loopTheChilds = function ( operation ) {

    $.each ( childs, function ( idx, val ) {
        $( val )[operation]();
    });

}
```

My gol would be to obtain this

```
$( "#foo" ).trigger("change");
$( "#bar" ).trigger("change");

// or

$( "#foo" ).prop( 'disabled', true );
$( "#bar" ).prop( 'disabled', true );
```

Or know how to get the same result in any other way.

Thanks

Comment: It is possible with eval(), but using eval() is considered as bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell javascript what code to execute as a string unless you use `eval` but as mentioned in the comments this is not very safe and generally not recommended. What you can do however is make your `loopTheChilds` method take a function as parameter, and that function has a parameter with a reference to the element.

So you could end up doing something like so:

```
var childs = ["#foo", "#bar"];

loopTheChilds(function(elem) {
    elem.trigger('change');
});

loopTheChilds(function(elem) {
    elem.prop('disabled', true);
});

function loopTheChilds(func) {
    $.each(childs, function(idx, elemName) {
        func($(elemName)); //wrap in jquery selector
    });
}
```

Now you just pass along the function you want to execute when you call the `loopTheChilds` method.

Working demonstration here: https://jsfiddle.net/phpyn1t6/

Comment: It's not exactly what I was thinking to was, but it seems to me an excellent solution. Thank you